# Multiple Inputs to MixingWaveProvider cause quality to suffer

Tags: c#, voip, naudio

I am making a VOIP program for fun, and I got it mostly working. Since my last question, another issue has come up. When there are two or more voices being played through the client using a MixingWaveProvider, there are strange stutters, clicks, snaps, and static in the final mixed audio. Most of the time, it sounds like a portion of someone's voice plays, pauses, and lets another person's voice play for a short while. This continues for as long as both are talking (Each voice seems to "take turns" outputting to the waveMixer).

I won't bother posting the Speex encoding/decoding code, as this issue happens with or without it being used. I get the input through a WaveInEvent, which feeds it's information into a UDP network stream. The UDP stream sends the sound data to the other clients.

Here is the code that I use to initialize the WaveOut and MixingWaveProvider32:

```
waveOut = new DirectSoundOut(settings.GetOutputDevice(), 50);
waveMixer = new MixingWaveProvider32();
waveOut.Init(waveMixer);
waveOut.Play();
```

When a client connects, I input the received packet data into the user's BufferedWaveProvider:

```
provider = new BufferedWaveProvider(format) { DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true };
wave16ToFloat = new Wave16ToFloatProvider(provider);
```

After that, I use this code to add the above 32bit provider to the MixingWaveProvider32:

```
waveMixer.AddInputStream(wave16ToFloat);
```

It seems that the issue is less severe with streams added before MixingWaveProvider32 is passed to WaveOut. However, I really need to be able to add them dynamically. Assuming that is why this happens.

This may have something to do with my network implementation, so I will look into that if something else isn't found here. Could it be possible that each voice data packet is blocking the next one from being read, thus causing the back and forth kind of sound? If so, how could I buffer the data on the server longer or wait to send in larger chunks on the client?

**Edit:**

I am almost sure that this is caused by the BufferedWaveProviders draining completely several times a second. The packets are not filling them fast enough, and they drain leaving nothing left to transmit. As I asked above, is there any way that I can send them from the client in large chunks? Or can I make the buffers drain slower somehow?

**Edit 2:**

I have now implemented a auto pausing buffer that will make sure it stays filled. The buffer unpauses when it's internal buffer goes above 1 second of sound, and it pauses when the data gets below .5 seconds. However, the buffer hovers around 1 second of sound, and I have checked that it is not running out/pausing the sound mid stream. Though this should be a good thing, the sound distortion still exists, and it is just as bad as before. It seems to be something wrong with the mixer or my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have already diagnosed the problem. If the BufferedWaveProviders aren't filling up then you will get silence. You need to implement some kind of auto-pause that delays playback until there is enough buffered audio. A cheating way to do this is to start off each buffer with five seconds of silence, allowing hopefully another five seconds of audio to be received while this buffer plays out.

Comment: I have added a new edit that explains what happened when I did this.

Comment: another thing to be careful of when mixing is the possibility of clipping. Have you checked whether any samples are going above +/- 1.0?

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. The Mixer was outputting values > 1. I ended up making the WaveOut device turn its self down to compensate for the overly loud volumes.